# Are there processes that can't be stopped?

Tags: process

1. Are there processes, once suspended (by ctrl-z), can't run correctly
   after resume (by `fg`)? What kinds are they?
2. Are there processes that can't be suspended at all? What kinds are they?

I just want to know if it is always safe to suspend a process.

Thanks.

Comment: Tim, from your other question about `top`, I am curious what your stopped processes are. what does `ps -e -o state,pid,cmd | grep ^T`, show, if anything?

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198478/does-cpulimit-stop-a-process  What do you mean by grep ^T?

Comment: Well, a process in uninterruptible sleep can't be stopped, woken up, killed, or otherwise affected. Process state `T`, which is what Doug is asking for, is "stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced" (see `man ps`).

Comment: @muru: you mean suspension doesn't work on them, or they can be suspended but will not run correctly after suspension?

Comment: @Tim Nothing works on them. They are effectively immune to everything except whatever caused the uninterruptible sleep (which is usually waiting for some resource).

Comment: how do you explain the question at unix.se?

Comment: @muru, not quite true... they can't be affected until the uninterruptable sleep ends, which is usually pretty soon, and then when the kernel returns to user space, the suspend is processed, so it isn't *immune*, it is simply delayed.

Comment: @psusi tell that to the firefox process stuck in US waiting for the files in an NFS mounted home directory to come.

Comment: @muru, yes, nfs is the one bad actor that still plagues us with long running uninterruptable sleep... yet it still does suspend when the uninterruptable sleep finally does finish.

Comment: @psusi Of course when it finishes, it becomes receptive to signals. What made you think otherwise?

Comment: so do you all think that all processes can be suspended and resumed without problems? regardless of delay or not.

Comment: @muru, the word *immune* implies that trying to suspend it simply has no effect and it will continue running as if you did not suspend it, as opposed to the suspend being delayed.

Comment: `grep ^T` means "hit" if "T" is the first character of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Full screen terminal applications ( think `nano` ) that are badly written/broken can fail to resume properly in that they don't repaint the screen correctly after its contents changed while the program was suspended.  Well behaved applications notice when they have been suspended and resumed and will repaint the screen properly.  That's about it.